# Extract text sting from <div> and <class> combined for JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, string, text, extract

I have the following HTML code.

```
<div data-stid="content-title" class="uitk-spacing uitk-spacing-padding-small-blockend-three uitk-spacing-padding-large-block-three">
  <div class="uitk-flex uitk-flex-align-items-center uitk-flex-gap-two uitk-type-300 all-b-padding-two">
    <span class="uitk-badge-text">VIP Access</span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="uitk-type-display-700">THE TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

With this function, I am able to pull out "THE TITLE".

```
function getTitle(domain) {

    let title = false;

    switch (domain) {
        case 'exite':
            title = $('.uitk-type-display-700');
            break;
    }
    return title;
}
```

However, it also pulls out anything else which has the same class. The unique ID in the HTML is `data-stid = "content-title"` but I am unable to find a way to make the function work.

***BELLOW is not working***

`#content-title`
`.content-title`
`[data-stid="content-title"]`
`.uitk-type-display-700 h1`
`.uitk-type-display-700 #h1`
`.uitk-type-display-700`
`[data-stid="content-title"]`
`.uitk-type-display-700 .content-title`

`.uitk-type-display-700` works but it picks up all other `.uitk-type-display-700` as well.

Thank you so much for your help.

Update
Neihter can I extract form this HTML with Div

```html
<div class="_styling-h1 hotel-name" title="R2 Maryvent Beach" data-tooltip-mobile="R2 Maryvent Beach">
```

Comment: how about `[data-stid="content-title"] .uitk-type-display-700`?

Comment: unfortunately that is not working either Pete. When I do that the function stops working also, as with all the others.